# Pandas - "Smart" Way of Summing Up Previous Values at Index 'n'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to working with pandas, and I've been trying to create a new dataframe where the price value at index `n` is the sum of the values from indices `0` to `n`.

For example, if I have:

```
dataframe df:

  price
0   1
1   2
2   3 
3   2
4   4 
5   2
```

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
dataframe df:

  price
0   1
1   3
2   6
3   8
4   12
5   14
```

I can think of a messy way of doing it using nested `for` loops, but I'm trying to shy away from using costly methods and doing things a more "sophisticated" way. But I can't really seem to think of a better method of doing this, and I know there has to a better way. What is the smart way of getting this "sum" dataframe? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the cumulative sum, for which you can use [`df.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df.cumsum()
```

Which returns:

```
   price
0      1
1      3
2      6
3      8
4     12
5     14
```